# Unexpected Result in Macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a simple program to calculate the volume of a cube. It runs fine, but the result I get is wrong. It comes out as "Y is 392". Can anyone help me understand why it is 392? I have just begun C, so I do not understand all of the code.

I realise this Macro is badly written, I am just trying to understand its behavior before I rewrite it.

```
#define CUBE(x) (x*x*x)

void main(void);

void main(void){
    int x, y;
    x = 5; 
    y = CUBE(++x);
    printf("Y is %d \n", y);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior or false positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129239/undefined-behavior-or-false-positive)

Comment: @mungpstrap if you still don't understand the problem from other answers/comments, examine the output of `gcc -E your source.c`. This will run the preprocessor (to expand the macro) and show you what actual source gets compiled... perhaps it will be more clear then.

Comment: @mah, 

Ok thanks I will try look into that, although there has been some good explanations here. Still this may be useful in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the macro expands to:

```
y = ++x * ++x * ++x;
```

This is a very badly written macro, for this very reason; it looks like a function call (which would evaluate the argument only once) but it really evaluates it three times.

This gives undefined behavior since there is a lack of [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: And even worse because of the lack of parentheses. `CUBE(1+2)`?

Comment: Use an inline function for this kind of thing. `inline int CUBE(int x) { return x * x * x; }`

Comment: So why is that not 6*6*6(216)

I can appreciate that it is badly written, it is not my code, I was just trying to understand its behaviour.

Comment: @mungostrap Because it's undefined behavior. **Anything** could happen during that line of code.

Comment: Because `#define`d macros expand through textual replacement. Each token `x` in `(x*x*x)` is replaced by your actual parameter string `++x`, resulting in `(++x*++x*++x)`. If you're on unix, try looking at the preprocessor output with a command like `gcc -E myprog.c`

Comment: It would invoke undefined behaviour even with `#define CUBE(x) ((x) * (x) * (x))` and `y = CUBE(x++);`. Need to be careful and sparing with macros and functional macros in particular.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that the macro pre-processor substitutes the parameters as they are. So, `CUBE(++x)` is expanded to:

```
++x*++x*++x
```

You should avoid using expressions with side effects in macros because of this.